# writeFile don't find directory

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am practicing a simple application that reads and writes to a file.
I'm using **writeFile** from **"fs/promises"**

When I import the file with the correct string I get the desired file

```
const content: Employe_T_nodel[] = require('../databace/employees.json')
```

But when I try to write to the file, I get an error:
no such file or directory, open 'D: ...

This is the code I use.
Note that I use the exact same string

```
async function saveAllEmployeesAsync(employeesArr: Employe_T_nodel[]) {
    const content: string = JSON.stringify(employeesArr)
    await writeFile('../databace/employees.json', content)
    return console.log("Employees saved sucsessfuly")
}
```

I don't understand why one function gets the path string and one doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `require()` treats paths as relative to the current file, while `fs.writeFile` treats paths as relative to the path from which the Node.js process was started from.

If you want the same behavior you can use [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

```js
async function saveAllEmployeesAsync(employeesArr: Employe_T_nodel[]) {
    const content: string = JSON.stringify(employeesArr)
    await writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../databace/employees.json'), content)
    return console.log("Employees saved sucsessfuly")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
fs.writeFile(dir, data, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("File not saved!   ", err);
    return err;
  } else {
    console.log("File saved!");
    return 200;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.